# Select dropdown list accessibility/usability

Tags: forms, select, drop-down-menu, accessibility, usability

I am trying to find the most usable/accessible way to implement a simple form dropdown list which will sort a list of products by pice and alphabetical order.

In your opinion is the dropdown more usable when there is a button that governs its submission or when it automatically submits onchange of the dropdown?

The research I have read is both for and against such methods and there is a variery of implementations on the web so interest to hear the thoughts of the community.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you do not change focus or navigate to another page when the selection changes, either approach should work. The classic example of a problem dropdown is where it contains a list of other pages on the site, and navigates as soon as the selection changes. This prevents a keyboard user from using the list; they can't browse it, and can't navigate to any pages beyond the first selection, since it's impossible to navigate past those. So in cases where focus changes or the page navigates as a consequence, having a separate action (eg. Go button, or handling enter) to cause the navigation to take place is *essential*. This is likely where the advice you've read is coming from.

In this case, however, it sounds as though you are just updating content elsewhere on the page, and not changing focus or doing navigation. Simply resorting existing content should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As a blind computer user either method works fine. I find that having a button to click is slightly easier for me then the onchange event firing. I wouldn't say it's a big enough difference to take into account though assuming the majority of your users will not be disabled. If your targeting specifically blind users I would not use the onchange event.

Comment: Interesting Jared! Why is the onchange event only slighty harder for you? Can you explain more in detail how you navigate a dropdown list (select-html-tag) as a blind user? I assume the screen reader reads all list items and you then decide which item you select?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your users and their respective expectations and the context in which it's presented.

As a blanket, general statement, you should have the drop down accompanied by very obvious submission button. That is the safer approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are refreshing page data or if the focus moves away after the dropdown option is selected, you should use a button to be accessible. If you fire the event on change, blind or keyboard-only users will not be able to use the dropdown menu at all if they are on windows with ie and chrome (so added together, a majority of the people on windows). As soon as they use the arrows to scroll down and make a selection, the first option they hit will be selected and the page data will refresh or the focus will move, making it impossible for them to navigate or select the second option, third option, etc. Below is a thorough explanation with examples so you can see what I mean.

Designers definitely don't like the buttons, but if you are blind and on chrome/ie, it is impossible to use a lot of dropdowns without it. I'm guessing Jared uses firefox or a mac.

http://pauljadam.com/blog/javascript/onchange-event-on-a-select-inputjump-menu-accessibility-problems/